Rendering only one label using QGIS


How do I render only one label per feature? (One Av. Bennett instead of 4).
I am using QGIS version 3.36.3 and the function merge connected lines to avoid duplicate doesn`t seem to exist.

Look at Processing GDAL Vector geoprocessing Dissolve.  There is also a Vector geometry Dissolve tool.  These will "merge" connected lines with the same attribute value you set and then you can label that.

it worked! thanks! :))
